# PhpStorm insert & overwrite cursor style reversed

Tags: php, insert, phpstorm, editor, text-cursor

I am having problems with the editor cursor.

When I enter the code in the editor with a blinking cursor, the cursor styles of insert mode and overwrite mode are reversed with each other on the screen.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Open menu "Help" -> "Find action...". Type "overwrite" into opened window and then double-click "Toggle Insert/Overwrite" item which is highlighted after typing. This will toggle current cursor mode.

In Windows, it [toggling] is probably may be achieved with just hitting "Ins" button on your keyboard, no need to find an action in menu. By default the keyboard key toggles insert/overwrite mode in many programs. But I'm not sure it will work because I did not use PhpStorm with Windows at all.

Answer (score 4):

Appears to be some setting with Editor->General->Apperance

See here:

[image]

Comment: I was about to go crazy!!!! This is why you don't fiddle with the settings when you're bored... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Hit on `Insert` button!,You can toggle it by hitting Vise Versa in to overwrite mode , normal mode editor!